# Strange Related List Error on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, redirect

I have a visualforce page on a custom object that redirects to several visualforce pages based on record type and profile of the user. For two out of three of the conditions, it works great. For the last one I get the following error:

> 'NotesAndAttachments' is not a valid child relationship name for
>   entity Inspection

NotesAndAttachments works fine on the two other pages.

The redirect VF is as follows:

```
<apex:page standardController="Inspection__c">
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(Inspection__c.RecordTypeId ='XXXXXXXXX',true,false)}">
<apex:include pageName="inspection" />
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(Inspection__c.RecordTypeId='XXXXXXXXX' && ($Profile.Name != 'System Administrator' || $Profile.Name != 'SLH QA with export'),true,false)}">
<apex:include pageName="inspectionRejected" /> 
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(Inspection__c.RecordTypeId ='XXXXXXXXX' && ($Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' || $Profile.Name = 'SLH QA with export'),true,false)}">
<apex:include pageName="InspectionRejectedAdmin" /> 
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

I even copied the exact code from the inspectionRejected VF page onto inspectionRejectedAdmin to no avail.

The InspectionRejectedAdmin code is as follows:

```
<apex:page standardController="Inspection__c" id="inspection" label="inspection" setup="false" extensions="inspectionExtension,extattachfile" sidebar="false">
<apex:form >
                  <apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Inspection__c.Send_Refresh_Email, Id)}" id="editButton" value="Send Refresh Email"/>
</apex:form>

<apex:tabPanel >

    <apex:tab label="General">
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!Inspection__c.Name}+" columns="2">
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Account__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.RecordTypeId}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Owner__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Contact__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Number_or_name_of_room__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.inspector_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Inspection_Date__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Checkout_date__c}"/> 
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Total_Quality_Score__c}" />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Inspection_Score__c}" />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.MySLH_Inspection_Colour__c}" />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Demo_Salesforce_Added__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Inspection_Id__c}" Label="Inspection Id"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.CreatedDate}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.MySLH_Stage__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Termination_Letter_Sent__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Expenses__c}"/>
            </apex:pageblockSection></apex:pageBlock>
          <br/>
          Comments:<i> {!Inspection__c.Inspection_Comments__c}</i>
          <br/>
          <apex:relatedList subject="{!Inspection__c}" list="NotesAndAttachments" />
        <apex:pageBlock title="Quality scores" >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Overall Evaluation" columns="2">
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Overall_Service__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Overall_Staff__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Overall_Accommodation__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Overall_Food__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Overall_Housekeeping__c}"   />       
            </apex:pageblockSection>
<apex:pageBlockSection title="General Comments" columns="1">
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Is_the_hotel_a_worthy_member_of_SLH__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Left_in_doubt_is_a_Small_Luxury_Hotel__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Would_book_again__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Would_encourage_selecting_another_SLH__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Confidence_in_Hotel__c}"   />    
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Further_Comments__c  }"   />   

            </apex:pageblockSection>

        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:tab>
    <apex:tab label="Reservation">
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Reservation Summary" columns="2">
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.SLH_Directory_and_Website__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.SLH_Directory_and_Website_Comments__c}"   />      
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.SLH_Membership_Registration_Procedure__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.SLH_Membership_Registration_Comments__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.SLH_Central_Reservation__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.SLH_Central_Reservation_Comments__c}"   />
            </apex:pageblockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Items" columns="1" >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SLHDirectory}" var="items">
<apex:facet name="header">SLH Directory</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}" style="text-align:center;"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}" style="text-align:center;"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }" style="text-align:center;"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SLHWebsite}" var="items">
<apex:facet name="header">SLH Website</apex:facet>

<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}" style="text-align:center;" />
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!MembershipRegistrationWebReservation}" var="items">
<apex:facet name="header">Membership Registration and Web Reservation</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Reservation}" var="items">
<apex:facet name="header">Reservations</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:tab>
<apex:tab label="Arrival">
<apex:pageblock >
     <apex:pageBlockSection title="Arrival Summary" columns="2">
        <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Arrival__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Arrival_Comments__c}"   />
     </apex:pageblockSection>
     <apex:pageBlockSection title="Items" columns="1" >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Arrival}" var="items" >
<apex:facet name="header">Arrival</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageblock>
 </apex:tab>
 <apex:tab label="Housekeeping/Room">
   <apex:pageblock >
     <apex:pageBlockSection title="Housekeeping/Room Summary" columns="2">
         <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Housekeeping_Bedroom__c}"   />
         <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Housekeeping_Bedroom_Comments__c}"   />
         <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Housekeeping_Bathroom__c}"   />   
         <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Housekeeping_Bathroom_Comments__c}"   />        
         <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Bedroom__c}"   />
         <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Bedroom_Comments__c}"   />
         <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Bathroom__c}"   />
         <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Bathroom_Comments__c}"   />
                </apex:pageblockSection>
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Items"  columns="1">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Bedroom}" var="items" >
<apex:facet name="header">Bedroom</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Bathroom}" var="items" >
<apex:facet name="header">Bathroom</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!HousekeepingBedroom}" var="items" >
<apex:facet name="header">Housekeeping</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }" />
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:tab>
<apex:tab label="Services">
<apex:pageblock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Services Summary" columns="2">
        <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Concierge_Services__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Concierge_Services_Comments__c}"   />
                        <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Telephone_Switchboard_Messages__c}"   />
        <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Telephone_Switchboard_Messages_Comments__c}"   />
 </apex:pageblockSection>
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Items" columns="1">


<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!TelephoneMessage}" var="items" >
<apex:facet name="header">Telephone Messages</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }" />
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ConciergeService}" var="items">
<apex:facet name="header">Concierge Services</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }" />
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
 </apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:tab>
<apex:tab label="Public Areas">
<apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Public Areas Summary" columns="2">
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Reception_Entrance_Hall__c}"   />
                                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Reception_Entrance_Hall_Comments__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Lounge_Seating_Area__c}"   />
                               <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Lounge_Seating_Area_Comments__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Staircases_Lifts_Corridors__c}"   />
                                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Staircases_Lifts_Corridors_Comments__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Toilets__c}"   />
                                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Toilets_Comments__c}"   />
            </apex:pageblockSection>
             <apex:pageBlockSection title="Items" columns="1">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Reception}" var="items">
<apex:facet name="header">Public Areas</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }" />
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageblockSection>


</apex:pageblock>
</apex:tab>
<apex:tab label="Pool & Leisure">
<apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Pool & Leisure Summary" columns="2">
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.External_Grounds__c}"   />
                                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.External_Grounds_Comments__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Pool_Beach_Services__c}"   />
                                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Pool_Beach_Services_Comments__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Leisure_Spa_Facilities__c}"   />
                                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Leisure_Spa_Facilities_Comments__c}"   />
            </apex:pageblockSection>
                         <apex:pageBlockSection title="Items" columns="1">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ExternalGround}" var="items" >
<apex:facet name="header">External Grounds</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }" />
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!PoolBeach}" var="items" >
<apex:facet name="header">Pool and Beach Service</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }" />
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!LeisureSpa}" var="items" >
<apex:facet name="header">Leisure/Spa facilities</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }" />
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:tab>
<apex:tab label="Dining">
<apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Dining Summary" columns="2">
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Main_Restaurant__c}"   />
                                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Main_Restaurant_Comments__c}"   />
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Room_Service__c}"   />
                   <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Room_Service_Comments__c}"   />             
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Bar_Lounge__c}"   />
                        <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Bar_Lounge_Comments__c}"   />        
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Breakfast__c}"   />
                          <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Breakfast_Comments__c}"   />      
            </apex:pageblockSection>
                                     <apex:pageBlockSection title="Items" columns="1">

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!MainRestaurant}" var="items">
<apex:facet name="header">Main Restaurant</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }" />
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!RoomService}" var="items">
<apex:facet name="header">Room Service</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }" />
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!BarLounge}" var="items">
<apex:facet name="header">Bar/Lounge</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }" />
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Breakfast}" var="items">
<apex:facet name="header">Breakfast</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }" />
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
 </apex:pageblockSection>


</apex:pageblock>
</apex:tab>
<apex:tab label="Departure">
<apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Departure" columns="2">
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Departure_Checkout__c}"   />
                 <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Departure_Checkout_Comments__c}"   />
                 <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.SLH_Brand_Values__c}"   />               
                 <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.SLH_Brand_Values_Comments__c}"   />              
             </apex:pageblockSection>
             <apex:pageBlockSection title="Items" columns="1">

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Departure}" var="items">
<apex:facet name="header">Departure</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }" />
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>


    </apex:pageblockSection>


</apex:pageblock>
</apex:tab>
<apex:tab label="SLH Brand">
<apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Departure" columns="2">
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Departure_Checkout__c}"   />
                 <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Departure_Checkout_Comments__c}"   />
                 <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.SLH_Brand_Values__c}"   />               
                 <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.SLH_Brand_Values_Comments__c}"   />              
             </apex:pageblockSection>
             <apex:pageBlockSection title="Items" columns="1">

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SLHBrandValue}" var="items">
<apex:facet name="header">SLH Brand Values</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }" />
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageblockSection>


</apex:pageblock>
</apex:tab>
<apex:tab label="Service Recovery">
<apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Service Recovery" columns="2">
                <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Departure_Checkout__c}"   />
                 <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.Departure_Checkout_Comments__c}"   />
                 <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.SLH_Brand_Values__c}"   />               
                 <apex:outputField value="{!Inspection__c.SLH_Brand_Values_Comments__c}"   />              
             </apex:pageblockSection>
             <apex:pageBlockSection title="Items" columns="1">

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ServiceRecovery}" var="items">
<apex:facet name="header">Service Recovery</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="40%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }" />
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageblockSection>


</apex:pageblock>
</apex:tab>
<apex:tab label="Other Items">
<apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Other Items - Errors or need Visualforce changes to Accommodate" columns="1">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!OtherItems}" var="items" >
<apex:facet name="header">Other Items</apex:facet>
<apex:column value="{!items.Q_ID__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Name}" width="30%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Mark__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.SLH_Value_earned__c }"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.section__c }" width="20%"/>
<apex:column value="{!items.Item_comments__c }" width="30%" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:tab>
<apex:tab label="Activity History">
<apex:relatedList subject="{!Inspection__c}" list="ActivityHistories" />
</apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>




</apex:page>


  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
```

Thanks in advance for everyone's help.

Comment: I suggest you check your record type definitions for the profiles and objects. It's likely the problem is one of point and click configuration related to profile permissions for the page and record type for the objects, not one that's in your page code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Salesforce doesn't use list="NotesAndAttachments" any longer. Now it's called CombinedAttachments.

```
<apex:relatedList subject="{!Inspection__c}" list="CombinedAttachments" />
```

Who knows why.

Answer (score 2):

This change happened quite a while ago now. You can see it announced in the [Winter '14 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_forcecom_attachments_related_list.htm).

> ## Changed Relationship Name for Notes and Attachments Related List
>
> The relationship name for the Notes and Attachments related list has changed.
>   `CombinedAttachments` now provides data for the Notes and Attachments related list. Until now, `NotesAndAttachments` was the relationship name used to provide data for this related list. For example, when creating a Visualforce page, this sample generates the Notes and Attachments related list on an account:
>
> ```
> <apex:relatedList subject="{!account}"
>     list="CombinedAttachments" />
> ```

Comment: i really should read those release notes. :)